Darlington transistor for low side switching of LED light
I have a circuit that is aimed to switch on a 48V LED light (front/rear) for a bike.
Basically a low side switch using a darlington transistor to be controlled by a 3.3V microcontroller.
On my simulation with LTSpice, I am seeing ~2.3A current on my transistor which is more than the transistor can handle.
May I ask what am I doing wrong here?


A single LED is not an accurate model for a 48 Volt LED module. Your LED module may contain many LEDs in series with a series resistor, or it may be more complicated.

The main problem is that you are not using the correct LED model. You write that you are using a 48V LED, but there are no such beasts (to my knowledge). What you have is some sort of package that may look liked a LED but is either many LEDs connected in series to look about right when you connect 48 volts, or a more advanced package with built-in regulation and voltage conversion.
The LED model you have chosen to use is a plain white LED rated for about 3.4 volts at 350 mA. Try putting 14 of them in series, or better yet, tell us the exact LED and link to its datasheet and a better solution may be given.

This is the light I was trying to control with the Darlington transistor. https://es.aliexpress.com/item/1005004382601102.html?gatewayAdapt=glo2esp

This would be like charging a 3.4V battery with 48V as the LED looks like a 1 Ohm load above 3V at 3.4V.
This will never work and short out the 48V.  What works may be to use the LED with a  3.3V to 3.4V supply, if it is an SMPS-regulated output with adequate power to connect the LED Anode or another SMPS regulator from 48V.  It won't work if the 3.3V is a linear regulator likely from heat rise.
https://luxeonstar.com/wp-content/uploads/documentation/ds25.pdf
This is an obsolete 3.4V nominal 1W LED.
The Darlington has an Rce bulk resistance of 2 to 3 Ohms ( from Vce(sat)/Ic=Rce) which limits the LED current and also burns up both parts.
